# Right using monorepo for ts-node scripts

Tags: node.js, source-code, repository, typescript, monorepo

I have a repository with various tools/scripts written with ts-node and used in many projects.

Initially, it contained several automation/analytics scripts, one package.json file at the root, and one index.ts file as an entry point.

I just uncomment the one call to the function I need and type `npm start`. Debugging in VS Code is also pretty easy with one config set up for index.ts.

But over time, the code base has grown and there are already ~ 40 scripts / tools that use different APIs and each other, the old approach is getting worse and worse.

Problems:

- unmaintainable index.ts with many imports, many commented lines
- long startup time (due to all unused imports)

What I want:

1. Each tool is in its own folder, as before
2. All tools use a single deps/node_modules at the root, as before
3. Tools can use common "libraries" (another tools) with no/minimum friction
4. I can start the specified (or opened in editor?) tool with a single command, and it's as easy as `npm start`
5. I can debug the specified tool with a single VS Code configuration.
6. I can add new tools, and there is no/minimum friction to register them in the monorepo, run and debug them without creating configurations.

I started looking into lerna, nx, npm workspaces, turborepo, lage, all of them seem to solve points 1-3 but not points 4-6.

How can I organise this monorepo to achieve the goals I outlined above?

Comment: I removed the request for a tool recommendation, which is off-topic for this community. I also saw one close-vote due to asking for assistance with writing or debugging code. To the down and close voters: I do not think the heart of this question is "what tool do I use" or "how do I write this code." The root of this question comes down to application design and version control strategy. While this question might still be a little broad, the two existing close votes are absolutely not applicable, IMO.

Comment: It sounds like you're listening for a single top-level URL, and you manually edit its function to enable desired functionality of the moment. To fix, configure several URL endpoints which dispatch to several functions of interest. Notice that you can pass in argument values as well, e.g. `/search?q=keyword`

Answer (score 0):

Using a monorepo for managing TypeScript (TS) Node scripts can provide several benefits, including:

Code Sharing: A monorepo can allow you to share common code and libraries across multiple projects. This can help reduce code duplication and make it easier to maintain and update shared code.

Consistency: A monorepo can help ensure consistency in your codebase by allowing you to enforce common standards and practices across all your projects.

Better Collaboration: By having all your projects in one place, it can be easier for team members to collaborate on code and make changes across different projects.

To use a monorepo for managing TS Node scripts, you can use a tool like Yarn Workspaces or Lerna to manage your packages and dependencies. These tools provide a convenient way to manage dependencies and build your projects.

Here are some steps you can follow to set up a monorepo for managing TS Node scripts:

Create a new folder for your monorepo and initialize a new npm package by running npm init or yarn init.

Add a packages folder where you can store all your TS Node scripts. Each script should be in its own folder under the packages folder.

In each script folder, create a package.json file with the appropriate dependencies and scripts.

In the root package.json file, add the workspaces property and specify the path to the packages folder.

Install Yarn Workspaces or Lerna as a dev dependency by running npm install --save-dev yarn or npm install --save-dev lerna.

Set up your scripts and dependencies in the root package.json file or create a separate scripts folder to manage them.

Run yarn install or lerna bootstrap to install all dependencies and link packages together.

You can now run your TS Node scripts using the scripts you defined in the root package.json file or the scripts folder.